# Проблема с tkinter в PyCharm Python

Tags: python, tkinter, pip

Всем добрый день. Работаю с Python с tkinter. Запускаю код в PyCharm, после чего выводит ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 908, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'TransformFinderLoader' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PycharmProjects/main/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tkinter.constants import *
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 910, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 884, in _find_spec_legacy
  File "C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\source_transform\meta_path.py", line 44, in find_module
    triggered_transforms = self.get_triggered_transforms()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\source_transform\meta_path.py", line 65, in get_triggered_transforms
    prot=mmap.PROT_READ
AttributeError: module 'mmap' has no attribute 'PROT_READ'
```

========================================================================================
Использую Python 3.8.2
Не понимаю в чем ошибка. Библиотеку уже устанавливал: pip install tkinter. Но если сейчас попробую ввести в командной строке "pip install tkinter", то выводит ошибку:

```
C:\Users>pip install tkinter
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 908, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'TransformFinderLoader' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 910, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 884, in _find_spec_legacy
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\source_transform\meta_path.py", line 44, in find_module
    triggered_transforms = self.get_triggered_transforms()
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\source_transform\meta_path.py", line 65, in get_triggered_transforms
    prot=mmap.PROT_READ
AttributeError: module 'mmap' has no attribute 'PROT_READ'
```

================================================================================================
А вот сам код, который пытаюсь запустить:

```
import tkinter

master = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master, bg='white', height=600, width=600)
canvas.pack()
for i in range(1, 9):
    canvas.create_line((0, 600 / 8 * i), (600, 600 / 8 * i), fill='black')
    canvas.create_line((600 / 8 * i, 0), (600 / 8 * i, 600), fill='black')
master.mainloop()
```

И так с любым кодом, если есть слова: import tkinter.
Подскажите пожалуйста как решить это. Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Сейчас заметил, что эта ошибка возникает при имортировании ЛЮБОЙ БИБЛИОТЕКИ, не только tkinter. Это произошло после обновления командной строки

Comment: Но если бы не обновлял командную строку, не мог импортировать новые библиотеки

Comment: Под Windows tkinter устанавливается вместе с Python, если поставить нужную галку при установке. Через pip tkinter не получится установить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"вы должны убедиться, что у вас подключена библиотека, через file-->settings"
file -> settings -> Project Interpreter -> + ? Так?
Но там я не могу найти ни python-tk, ни нужного мне turtle

Answer (score 3):

Все у вас работает. Запускается поле с клеточками. Вам нужно правильно подключить tkinter  к проекту. Для этого, вы должны убедиться, что у вас подключена библиотека, через  file-->settings.  Там в списке должен быть pip и привязана к нему нужная вам библиотека. Если вы устанавливаете библиотеку через командную строку, то не факт что указанный в Пайчарм интерпретатор её подцепит. Для установки библиотек необхоимо использовать средства Пайчарм, описанные мной выше.